# How is it possible to compile code from code

Tags: function, compilation, compiler-construction, code-generation

I want to experiment with the programs that write programs in C code, and i want to use construction like following:

```
int main() {
    char* srcCode="int f(int x) { return x+42; }";
    int (*compiledFun)(int) = compile(srcCode);
    printf("result=%d", (*compiledFun)(123));
    return 0;
}
```

Desired output should be printed "*result=165*".

My question is about `compile()` function. I may try to put `srcCode` in a file, then invoke external compiler, like `gcc`, then try to read produced binary, probably fix some addresses, and so to fill the `compiledFun` memory. But I feel like that would be a very inefficient *stub*. Is there any way to compile a program from within a program, directly from memory to memory? Maybe some library or a subset that can be ripped off gcc sources, responsible for producting binary code from source text?

---

That may be important addition, all source code that should be compiled is a function that takes arguments and returns. It will not call any external libraries and function like `printf`, but only do some calculations and return.

Comment: You could take a look at [`tcc`](https://bellard.org/tcc/), which includes a library with more or less this feature (I'm not sure if you can configure a sandbox, you'd have to read the docs). LLVM also includes this feature but it's not so easy to use. For future reference, "Help me find a tool" is usually considered off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @rici are you're being hostile to the OP? they have a programming problem, someone has to point them to the right place. This is not easily googled. The user did not know this is solved by a library that has to be recommended to them, they even thought that the same compiler could help, and they need to have that explained. If the question was like "please recommend the best library to compile C in memory" that would be a violation. Obviously user is at their first step here. Though my answer recommends a library, it also makes it obvious that you cannot solve it with ANSI C or GCC builtins.

Comment: @exebook: it certainly wasn't meant to be hostile, and rereading the comment, I don't think it comes off as hostile either. It provides two hopefully useful suggestions and then mentions a SO policy "for future reference", because the question literally asks "Maybe some library... ". If you disagree with that policy or the way it is worded in the guidelines, you could certainly take it up on meta. It does sometimes get weaponised and I have complained about that in the past.

Comment: @rici I have associated your comment with all the down/close votes, seems I was wrong and you were actually trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `libtcc` an in-memory C compiler from TinyC.

A complete example from here https://github.com/TinyCC/tinycc/blob/mob/tests/libtcc_test.c

```
/*
 * Simple Test program for libtcc
 *
 * libtcc can be useful to use tcc as a "backend" for a code generator.
 */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "libtcc.h"

/* this function is called by the generated code */
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

/* this strinc is referenced by the generated code */
const char hello[] = "Hello World!";

char my_program[] =
"#include <tcclib.h>\n" /* include the "Simple libc header for TCC" */
"extern int add(int a, int b);\n"
"#ifdef _WIN32\n" /* dynamically linked data needs 'dllimport' */
" __attribute__((dllimport))\n"
"#endif\n"
"extern const char hello[];\n"
"int fib(int n)\n"
"{\n"
"    if (n <= 2)\n"
"        return 1;\n"
"    else\n"
"        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"int foo(int n)\n"
"{\n"
"    printf(\"%s\\n\", hello);\n"
"    printf(\"fib(%d) = %d\\n\", n, fib(n));\n"
"    printf(\"add(%d, %d) = %d\\n\", n, 2 * n, add(n, 2 * n));\n"
"    return 0;\n"
"}\n";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    TCCState *s;
    int i;
    int (*func)(int);

    s = tcc_new();
    if (!s) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create tcc state\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* if tcclib.h and libtcc1.a are not installed, where can we find them */
    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        char *a = argv[i];
        if (a[0] == '-') {
            if (a[1] == 'B')
                tcc_set_lib_path(s, a+2);
            else if (a[1] == 'I')
                tcc_add_include_path(s, a+2);
            else if (a[1] == 'L')
                tcc_add_library_path(s, a+2);
        }
    }

    /* MUST BE CALLED before any compilation */
    tcc_set_output_type(s, TCC_OUTPUT_MEMORY);

    if (tcc_compile_string(s, my_program) == -1)
        return 1;

    /* as a test, we add symbols that the compiled program can use.
       You may also open a dll with tcc_add_dll() and use symbols from that */
    tcc_add_symbol(s, "add", add);
    tcc_add_symbol(s, "hello", hello);

    /* relocate the code */
    if (tcc_relocate(s, TCC_RELOCATE_AUTO) < 0)
        return 1;

    /* get entry symbol */
    func = tcc_get_symbol(s, "foo");
    if (!func)
        return 1;

    /* run the code */
    func(32);

    /* delete the state */
    tcc_delete(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent library, simple api, great for educational and researching purposes. That is exactly what i was looking for! And Happy New Year!